# At what point am I considered "critically injured"?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

There are some perks (Protect My Balls / Fight or Flight) and equipment patches that give bonuses only when the player character is "critically injured".

At what point are you considered "critically injured"? Is there a way to know for sure that a character is critically injured?

Answer (score 1):

When Critically injured, your health bar will flash. It applies to all or most character in the game.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the look of your character change as it gets injured. Once below a certain HP threshold, I'd like to say 20% but can't be to sure, the character will look beat up with blood running down the corner of its mouth and a black eye starting to form. The ability to spot this will of course depend on the attire you wear and the amount of other status effects currently on your character as they also feature visual cues.